# Make browser to wrap table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```
HTML:
<div id="table">
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
    <div class="table-cell"></div>
</div>

CSS:
#table {
    display: table;
    width: 940px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 220px;
    height: 282px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
}
```

Is it possible to make browser wrap table-cells after every 4 is added. I mean to create new row every 4 table-cell.

Thanks!

P.S. There is only 4 places for cells in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css:

```
#table {
    display: table;
    width: 940px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.table-row
{display:table-row;}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 220px;
    height: 282px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="table">
    <div class="table-row" >
        <div class="table-cell">1</div>
        <div class="table-cell">2</div>
        <div class="table-cell">3</div>
        <div class="table-cell">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row" >
        <div class="table-cell">1a</div>
        <div class="table-cell">2a</div>
        <div class="table-cell">3a</div>
        <div class="table-cell">4a</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

you say need automatically :

you can change css to :

```
#table {
    display: table;
    width: 960px !important;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.table-cell {
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 220px;
    height: 282px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
}
```

Comment: This way is obvious. I am asking if it is posiible to make wrap automatically and without table-row element. Just to wrap when #table is full.

Comment: can you use jquery in html file?

Comment: I know how to do it with jquery :)

Comment: It seems to me when I use float that display: table-cell stops taking effect. E.g. vertical aligning inside the cell.